# Where is bifurcation situated on cyclohexane isomerisation PES?

Tags: organic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, isomers, books

I am wondering what does PES for cyclohexane isomerisation looks like.

I have two possibilities in mind but each has some kind of vagueness.

1) Starting from boat conformation minimum, followed by transition state, then bifurcation, after that two separate paths leading to halfchair transition states and then chair minima.

I am wondering what this first transition state would look like? I can't seem to imagine conformation that would be different from boat but leading to two further conformational possibilities.

2) Starting form boat conformation minimum, followed by bifurcation, after that two separate paths leading to halfchair transition states and then chair minima.

In this case I am wondering how can bifurcation occur without valley ridge inflection point, and I can't seem to imagine valley ridge inflection point coming from boat minimum.

Aditional question: Does bifurcation occur only when moving on PES from global minimum?

I don't know if I'm missing some major point here, but any help is welcome.

Also any suggestions for some book or article about this?

Comment: You could model it.  GAMESS (US) is free, as is ORCA.

Comment: http://butane.chem.uiuc.edu/jsmoore/chem232/notes_current/Cycloalkanes/NOTES-The_Cyclohexane_Ring_Flip.pdf

Comment: http://www.ch.imperial.ac.uk/rzepa/blog/?p=7926

Comment: It says nothing about bifurcation on PES of cyclohexane in these articles. Additional help would be welcome.

Comment: @Martin 's article implies a bifurcation by noting two paths that pass through the same transition state. This is made more clear in the [precursor article] (http://www.ch.imperial.ac.uk/rzepa/blog/?p=1587) that is linked to in Martin's article and I have included here.

Comment: I don't know how helpful this will be, but still https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed047p488